# Custom fields for Stackdriver error reporting

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

Is there a way to send custom fields for Stackdriver error reporting?

There is a context field (https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages) but only with predefined fields.

Comment: There is a [texPayload](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry)  fild that you might be able to use. Otherwise may be try writing the logs using [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs) to interact with the [API itself](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/logging/v2).

Comment: Are you writing logs with errors, or reporting error events directly to the API? What kind of data are you hoping to include?

Comment: I guess the question is still relevant. Here are predefined fields https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-error_reporting/v0.32.0/Google/Cloud/ErrorReporting/ErrorEvent.html and I don't how to add custom. If I add an attribute to the Exception object I doubt it'll be seen in the web interface.