# Google Stackdriver Error Reporting API - Include Custom Data

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I need to include a custom data object/JSON string with an error report, without losing the stacktrace that Stackdriver seems to capture. Setting a JSON string as the `message` doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

I have seen references to a `jsonPayload` key online, but haven't had success setting it in the report.

In the Node.js systems I am integrating Stackdriver into (via logging client), I have a logger function that accepts additional data about the environment, the error stack and any supporting data that led to the error, and I wish to include this with the report so that they can be quickly investigated.

I have instead had to use the Google Stackdriver Logging API to handle this in the interim, but I find the metrics viewer a little convoluted and it's also hard to keep track of which logs have been dealt with.

I saw a [stale question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549231/custom-fields-for-stackdriver-error-reporting) on this previously, but didn't want to hijack it. Nor did it have any solution.

Hoping there's a solution!

Answer (score 2):

What I do is storing custom payload to Datastore and put the link to Datastore viewer to the error exception message. Here is for example how it looks in Ruby (the method stores `url` and `html` strings that I need for debug as attributes of the Datastore entity of kind `exception_details`):

```
def report_error url, html
  begin
    raise "https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query/gql?gql=#{
            CGI.escape "SELECT * FROM exception_details WHERE __key__=Key(exception_details, #{
              Datastore.save( Datastore.entity("exception_details") do |error|
                error["url"] = url
                error["html"] = html
                error.exclude_from_indexes! "html", true
              end ).first.key.id
            })"
          }"
  rescue => e
    Google::Cloud::ErrorReporting.report e
  end
end
```

Here is an email I get:

[image]

Instead of clicking the blue button I visit the hyperlink where I can now inspect the `html` variable that I stored:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response. Looks like a very good workaround. I’ll try it on my development branch. For now I have switched to using Sentry as it allows quick and simple setting of context